# Infopath2013 5 condition rule limit - expression work around syntax issue

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, infopath

This is my code to add an expression into a formatting rule in InfoPath 2013 0- I am trying to get around the 5 rule limit.

```
not(contains(my:Spec, "Select")) and not(contains(my:Spec, "001")) and not(contains(my:Spec, "004")) and not(contains(my:Spec, "005")) and not not(contains(my:Spec, "007")) and not(contains(my:Spec,"008")) and and not(contains(my:Spec,"028")) and not(contains(my:Spec,"030")) and not(contains(my:Spec,"042")) and not(contains(my:Spec,"044")) and not(contains(my:Spec,"047")) and not(contains(my:Spec,"048")) and not(contains(my:Spec,"052")) and not(contains(my:Spec,"058")) and not(contains(my:Spec,"060")) and not(contains(my:Spec,"062")) and not(contains(my:Spec,"063")) and not(contains(my:Spec,"068")) and not(contains(my:Spec,"070")) and not(contains(my:Spec,"071")) and not(contains(my:Spec,"074")) and not(contains(my:Spec,"075")) and not(contains(my:Spec,"076")) and not(contains(my:Spec,"086")) and not(contains(my:Spec,"087")) and not(contains(my:Spec,"10000022"))
```

However I get the following error when I try to save the rule:

**The following expression is not valid
Expected value type: end-of-string**

Can anyone help me out here - I have 70+ fields which I need to so the same hide/show options based on another single fields drop down box option selection (this one has 60-70 options to choose from)

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue - there were syntax errors in my original code - I has repeated not in the same part of the expression, hence the end string error message.

The correct code to use where you want something hidden based on a field NOT being a given condition is below.

```
not(contains(my:Spec, "Select")) and not(contains(my:Spec, "001")) and not(contains(my:Spec, "004")) and not(contains(my:Spec, "005")) and not(contains(my:Spec, "007")) and not(contains(my:Spec, "008")) and not(contains(my:Spec, "028")) and not(contains(my:Spec, "030")) and not(contains(my:Spec, "042")) and not(contains(my:Spec, "044")) and not(contains(my:Spec, "047")) and not(contains(my:Spec, "048")) and not(contains(my:Spec, "052")) and not(contains(my:Spec, "058")) and not(contains(my:Spec, "060")) and not(contains(my:Spec, "062")) and not(contains(my:Spec, "063")) and not(contains(my:Spec, "068")) and not(contains(my:Spec, "070")) and not(contains(my:Spec, "071")) and not(contains(my:Spec, "074")) and not(contains(my:Spec, "075")) and not(contains(my:Spec, "076")) and not(contains(my:Spec, "086")) and not(contains(my:Spec, "087")) and not(contains(my:Spec, "10000022"))
```

where Spec is the field whose selection the conditions are based upon, and the items in inverted commas are the conditions.

Feel a bit silly for answering my own question, but wanted to share the solution with all